# Flutter : How to Make just selected value is true in list view builder

Tags: flutter, listview, dart

I have a dynamic list of address coming from the api and I'm listing it in list view builder and I want to select one address by check box and make the another addresses check boxes value with false , how I can handle this point

this is my list view code

```
ListView.builder(
                                                itemCount: adminAcceptStatusAdd
                                                        .length ??
                                                    0,
                                                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                                  return Padding(
                                                      padding:
                                                          const EdgeInsets.all(
                                                              4.0),
                                                      child: Card(
                                                          color:
                                                              Colors.grey[200],
                                                          child: Padding(
                                                              padding:
                                                                  const EdgeInsets
                                                                          .all(
                                                                      10.0),
                                                              child: Column(
                                                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                                                      MainAxisAlignment
                                                                          .start,
                                                                  crossAxisAlignment:
                                                                      CrossAxisAlignment
                                                                          .start,
                                                                  children: [
                                                                    Row(
                                                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                                                          MainAxisAlignment
                                                                              .spaceBetween,
                                                                      children: [
                                                                        Padding(
                                                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                                              left: 4,
                                                                              right: 4),
                                                                          child:
                                                                              Container(
                                                                            width:
                                                                                MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .5,
                                                                            child:
                                                                                Text(
                                                                              adminAcceptStatusAdd[index]['title'],
                                                                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18),
                                                                            ),
                                                                          ),
                                                                        ),
                                                                        MyCheckbox(
                                                                            value: //isSelected,
                                                                                _isFalse[index],
                                                                            checkedFillColor: Constants.skyColor(),
                                                                            onChanged: (bool value) => setState(() {
                                                                                  //isFavourite[index] = true;
                                                                                  _isFalse[index] = !_isFalse[index];
                                                                                  // _isTrue[index] = false;
                                                                                })),
                                                                        
                                                                      ],
                                                                    ),
                                                                  ]))));
                                                })
```

Comment: I don't think this question is very clear. Can you describe and provide the code you already have implemented and describe the desired behavior more clearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to select one and only one address you should use RadioGroup instead of Checkbox

Comment: i will try it and back to you